# Riverbed Steelhead won't peer

Tags: riverbed

I have the simple Riverbed Steelhead setup as shown in the image:

[image]

The in-path interfaces can ping each other, however I'm unable to get the Steelheads to peer. Can someone shed some light on the problem? Even if I configure an In-Path rule with the 'Fixed-Target' to be address of the each in-path IP address, they still won't peer.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide configurations and log messages, without those we can only guess.

Comment: @Carltonp Have you tried with Auto-Discover and generated some interesting traffic? At the same time, try the command "nettest run peer-reach addr Peer_IP_Address" to run a Peer Reachability test.

Comment: Hi Hung, I have generated interesting traffic in the form of SMB traffic. I get the following from 'Current Connections,,Connection type: Intentional Passthrough
Connection age: 6 minutes, 25 seconds
Transport: TRANSPORT_ID_NONE
Passthrough reason: SYN on WAN side

Comment: @Teun, I'm not sure how to upload the configuration

Comment: @Hung, I have tried Auto-Discover and fixed target with no luck

Comment: @Carltonp have you tried the command `nettest run peer-reach addr Peer_IP_Address` to run a Peer Reachability test?

Comment: @carltonp you should copy/paste it as preformatted text using {{ and }}

Comment: @Carltonp I noticed that 'Passthrough reason' was 'SYN on WAN side', please check the cabling and LAN/WAN interfaces on the appliance, they could be wrongly plugged.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score -1):

If it takes you more than a day to stand these up, you're overthinking it. These things are super simple. Take manufacturers advice / best practises.

See [SteelHead™ Deployment Guide > Best Practices for SteelHead Deployments](https://support.riverbed.com/bin/support/static/fbunsuuo632vi3jrspe0evbko9/html/u2pi6l52l4drmhq3uhck9tu7hm/sh_9.2_dg_html/index.html#page/sh_9.2_dg%2Fdesignfund.html%23ww213544)

> •  **Use in-path designs** - Whenever possible, use a physical in-path
>   deployment—the most common type of SteelHead deployment. Physical
>   in-path deployments are easier to manage and configure than WCCP, PBR,
>   and Layer-4 designs. In-path designs generally require no extra
>   configuration on the connected routers or switches. If desired, you
>   can limit traffic to be optimized on the SteelHead. For details, see
>   Physical In-Path Deployments.

See Also [Configuring a Primary and Backup Deployment](https://support.riverbed.com/bin/support/static/fbunsuuo632vi3jrspe0evbko9/html/u2pi6l52l4drmhq3uhck9tu7hm/sh_9.2_dg_html/index.html#page/sh_9.2_dg%2Fphys_inpath_designs.html%23ww222988) for configs to copy& paste in.

```
1.  Connect to the primary SteelHead CLI and enter the following commands:

    -- Primary SteelHead.<br>
    interface primary ip address 10.0.1.2/24<br>
    ip default gateway 10.0.1.1<br>
    interface inpath0_0 ip address 10.0.1.3/24<br>
    ip in-path-gateway inpath0_0 10.0.1.1<br>
    -- Failover should point to the inpath0_0 address.<br>
    failover steelhead addr 10.0.1.5<br>
    failover master<br>
    failover enable<br>
    in-path enable<br>
    -- Although not required, RiOS data store synchronization is usually enabled
    -- in primary/backup deployments.<br>
    datastore sync master<br>
    -- RiOS data store should point to peer primary or aux interface address.<br>
    datastore sync peer-ip 10.0.1.4<br>
    datastore sync enable<br>
    write memory<br>
    restart<br>
2.  Connect to the backup SteelHead CLI and enter the following commands:
    -- Backup SteelHead.<br>
    interface primary ip address 10.0.1.4/24<br>
    ip default gateway 10.0.1.1<br>
    interface inpath0_0 ip address 10.0.1.5/24<br>
    ip in-path-gateway inpath0_0 10.0.1.1<br>
    -- Failover should point to the inpath0_0 address.<br>
    failover steelhead addr 10.0.1.3<br>
    no failover master<br>
    failover enable<br>
    in-path enable<br>
    -- Although not required, RiOS data store synchronization is usually enabled in
    -- primary/backup deployments.<br>
    no datastore sync master<br>
    -- RiOS data store should point to peer's primary or aux interface address.<br>
    datastore sync peer-ip 10.0.1.2<br>
    datastore sync enable<br>
    write memory<br>
    restart<br>
```

Comment: I totally agree, that is why this is so frustrating .. I have configured this in the past. Also, your configuration suggests I have physical Riverbed Appliances. I'm running Virtual SteelHead appliances.  This is driving me nutz

Comment: ip default-gateway "10.1.20.1"
   ip in-path fwm-route interface inpath0_0 target-addr "0.0.0.0"
   ip in-path-gateway inpath0_0 10.1.20.1 This part of my configuration

Comment: Steel Fusion Boxes?